# Is it important to to start the index with 1 in javascript Array indexOf() method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

Why w3school add +1 in this program?
The result shows that Apple is at 1 index,what's the reason of adding 1 in it?
...
...
...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Array.indexOf()</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
const fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Mango"];
let position = fruits.indexOf("Apple") +1;

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Apple is found in position " + position;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When i removed the +1 then it shows Apple is at 0 index which makes sense to me.

Comment: That's up to you; the general public doesn't start counting at 0 and thus would consider "position 1" to be Apple, rather than Orange. It depends on who your audience is and how you are using that value.

Comment: That example is meant to show the actual position (not the array index technically), hence adding +1 to the index.

`Apple` is at index `0` but in layman's terms, it is at position `1`

Comment: If you counting from 0, then I like your intuition :)

Answer (score 1):

w3school add the + 1 at the end for their demo just to say that the apple is in the first position of the array.
If you remove the +1, the program will display the actual index of the first occurrence of "Apple" in the array, which is 0, as expected.